# CSS - Transparent bg of image not rendering on website

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to redesign my site so that my original square, tile-based rendering of images can be more of a cutout of the image... to get rid of that grid pattern.

Here's how it looked originally...

[image]

Here's a rough mock-up of what I'm going for:

[image]

So I resaved an image thumbnail with a transparent background... I just want the dog to show, and the square is transparent which will show the site's background underneath.

[image]

Yet when I render it on the page, it has this black background.

[image]

I've checked my CSS to see if there is some sort of img class, or class for the rendered comics... or even the bootstrap to see where there may be a background-color being assigned to black (and also searched for hex code 000000), but didn't find one...

Do you know why this may be happening?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** I've just noticed something...

My logo at the top renders with a transparent background... and the element is a png file... therefore, its MIME type is image/png.

I'm using a thumbnailing script to make the thumbnails smaller, but now the element is of thumber.php, which puts it as MIME type image/jpeg.

[image]

So I guess it's my thumbnailing script that changing the MIME type.

So I checked it, and it's creating the file as a jpeg

```
//imagejpeg outputs the image
imagejpeg($img);
```

Is there a way to change it so that the resampled image is output as a png?

---

Thumbnailing script:

```
    <?php
#Appreciation goes to digifuzz (http://www.digifuzz.net) for help on this

$image_file = $_GET['img']; //takes in full path of image
$MAX_WIDTH = $_GET['mw'];
$MAX_HEIGHT = $_GET['mh'];
global $img;

//Check for image
if(!$image_file || $image_file == "") { 
    die("NO FILE."); 
}

//If no max width, set one
if(!$MAX_WIDTH || $MAX_WIDTH == "") { 
    $MAX_WIDTH="100"; 
}

//if no max height, set one
if(!$MAX_HEIGHT || $MAX_HEIGHT == "") { 
    $MAX_HEIGHT = "100"; 
}

$img = null;
//create image file from 'img' parameter string
$img = imagecreatefrompng($image_file);

//if image successfully loaded...
if($img) {
    //get image size and scale ratio
    $width = imagesx($img);
    $height = imagesy($img);

    //takes min value of these two
    $scale = min($MAX_WIDTH/$width, $MAX_HEIGHT/$height);

    //if desired new image size is less than original, output new image
    if($scale < 1) {
        $new_width = floor($scale * $width);

        $new_height = floor($scale * $height);


        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

        //copy and resize old image to new image
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagedestroy($img);

        //replace actual image with new image
        $img = $tmp_img;
    }
}
//set the content type header
header("Content-type: image/png");

//imagejpeg outputs the image
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagepng($img);

imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

Comment: can you put a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: My site's code is extensive... I'm not sure how to condense it into a fiddle

Comment: Oh and are you trying it in Internet Explorer? IE has a history of badly supporting transparency.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba Chrome for now

Comment: Right click on the element and on the menu Inspect Element, you will see all the css rules applied. Another thing is that photoshop has a few png save modes and you might be using one with the Alpha set to black(happens)

Comment: or make sure image is png24

Comment: @lemon郑 how do I specify saving as png24?

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba how do I specify the alpha? that option seems grey'ed out for me

Comment: Ok, make sure you are using Save for Web, and choose PNG-24 and just check the Transparency checkbox, if for some reason you want PNG-8 on the color table you have to pick a color and click the checkers button that reads Map selected colors to transparent.

Comment: try this image https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/google-logo-plus-0fbe8f0119f4a902429a5991af5db563.png

Comment: @lemon郑 that renders on the site with a transparent bg

Comment: so sure is you image problem...Save for Web => select png24 and checked transparen

Comment: @lemon郑 I found the issue, but don't know how to solve it. See update above

Comment: hope this help http://cn2.php.net/manual/zh/function.imagepng.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28405/discussion-between-growler-and-lemon)

Comment: @Growler: The same thing was happening with me , when i was trying a transparent image in visual basic script. Almost sucked me a lot, Then i changed image support With VB. Though it was supported to *jpg then, changed it to *Png.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make some changes in the image generator and see if that works out for you.
The crucial changes are within the setting of the header and the method of image generation. You will be looking for these following two

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

change to:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

---

```
imagejpeg($im);
```

change to:

```
imagepng($im)
```

When dealing with png images with an alpha channel you should take a few extra steps.
Before spitting it out with imagepng(), these lines will need to be added.

```
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

This information can be found on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php)

**Edit:**
Try with these alterations to this code:

```
 if($scale < 1) {
        $new_width = floor($scale * $width);

        $new_height = floor($scale * $height);


        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);


        imagealphablending($tmp_img,true); // add this line

        //copy and resize old image to new image
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        $img = $tmp_img;

        // remove line here
    }
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($tmp_img); // add this line here
```

Basically you create new layers and put these together. For each layer you will need to set the alpha blending. I was successful in creating alpha images. Let me know what your findings are .. :-) ..

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this answer will work by simply changing `jpeg` to `png`. I may be wrong, but wouldn't the entire script need to be changed as the compression would be different? Furthermore, you will have to make sure that alpha transparency is used in your PHP file, or it won't matter if the file is a `png`, `gif`, `jpeg`, `velociraptor`, `psd`...

Comment: Well.. saving it as a png is a good start to get what he wants. With jpeg generation he will never get the transparency to begin with. But you are correct that there may be more to deal with. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks daniel, but I've tried all of these things with no success. I found when I take the same image and directly add it `<img src="./images/Comics/ComicThumbnails/Animals.png" />` it is transparent... so there's definitely an issue with the thumbnailing script. I've added the entire thing above

Comment: @Growler Set imagealphablending($image,true); on each new layer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109832/php-gd-create-a-transparent-png-image

Comment: @Growler - You should be able to copy my edits into your thumbnail creator and have your issue solved. I made a final edit that implements it correctly into the thumbnail creator. Cheer! :-)